# google maps resize symbol on zoom not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm resizing the symbol this way:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map_object, 'zoom_changed', (function(arrow) { return function() {
    var zoom = map_object.getZoom();
    var scale = 2.48676567E-2 * Math.exp(0.143700035 * zoom);
    arrow.icons[0].icon.scale = scale;
}})(arrow));
```

When I inspect the arrow object, the `scale` property changes properly on `zoom_changed`, but it's not changing its size in the map.

Is there something I'm forgetting to do?

**UPDATE**
The arrow object is defined as follow:

```
var sym = {
    path: "M0 15 L30 0 L60 15",
    rotation: angle,
    scale: 0.25,
    strokeWeight: 3,
};
var arrow = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{lat: lat, lng: lng},{lat: lat2, lng: lng}],
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: color,
    strokeOpacity: 0.9,
    icons: [{
        icon: sym,
        offset: '100%'
     }]
});
```

Comment: What is `arrow`?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I think `arrow` is not relevant to the problem. Maybe the icon object. Anyway, please see my update

Answer (score 0):

Just for future references.

I solved my problem using the `setOptions` method from [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polyline) class, instead of setting the `scale` property.

My code becomes to this:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map_object, 'zoom_changed', (function(arrow) { return function() {
    var zoom = map_object.getZoom();
    var scale = 2.48676567E-2 * Math.exp(0.143700035 * zoom);
    var icon = arrow.icons[0].icon;
    icon.scale = scale;
    arrow.setOptions({icons: [{icon: icon, offset: '100%'}]});
}})(arrow));
```

Now, the arrow size is changing on map zoom in the right way.